# Google Kubernetes engine inter-cluster session affinity(Sticky Session)

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

The situation is that I have 2 applications: A and B that are in the same namespace of a cluster on gke. A is on 1 pod and B is on 2 pods.

Everytime a client communicates with our service. It connects first on A with websockets. A then sends http request to B. Since there is 2 pods of B, I would like to have session affinity between the Client from outside and with my application B so that everytime a client connects to A, it will always process his requests through the same pod of B.

Every session affinity option I saw are based on Ingress gateway or services, but since I'm already in the cluster, I don't need an Ingress.

I also saw that there is some services that provides support for http cookies. That would be good but it is always an external service like Nginx or Istio and since I'm working in a highly restricted development environment it is kind of a pain to add those service in the cluster.

Is there anything native to the gke that can provide me with http cookie session affinity or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a GKE cluster, when you create a Kubernetes Ingress object, the GKE ingress controller wakes up and creates a Google Cloud Platform HTTP(S) load balancer. The ingress controller configures the load balancer and also configures one or more backend services that are associated with the load balancer.

Beginning with GKE version 1.11.3-gke.18, you can use an Ingress to configure these properties of a backend service:

- Timeout
- Connection draining timeout
- Session affinity

[This](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/configure-backend-service#setting_generated_cookie_affinity) will be useful for you and it's native of GKE Ingress.

Answer (score 0):

> Everytime a client communicates with our service. It connects first on A with websockets. A then sends http request to B. Since there is 2 pods of B, I would like to have session affinity between the Client from outside and with my application B so that everytime a client connects to A, it will always process his requests through the same pod of B.

A communicate with B. A should connect to a specific instance of B depending on what end-user is connected to B.

This is **sharding** not *session affinity* but I understand what you mean. This means that your service B need a stable *network identity*.

### Sharding by User identity

Service B need to be deployed as a [StatefulSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-network-id) to get a stable *network identity*. Then Service A can do *sharding* e.g. based on *username* or a range of IP-address or something, so requests for **user X** is **always handled by instance Y**.

With Service B deployed as StatefulSet, the instances will be named e.g. `app-b-0` and `app-b-1` so each instance can be addressed from Service A with a stable identity.

Comment: The second request is from A to B(In the same cluster). The Only request coming from outside the cluster using an Ingress is the initial connection to A by websockets

Comment: I saw the link you sent in your response. I already tried implementing it and it didn't worked but after looking more into it, I think this is not meant for GKE but more for other part of the google cloud platform.

Comment: Yes the load balancer is outside GKE, but uses Ingress objects

Answer (score 0):

You could have set Client IP based session affinity, which happens at service level, like this one:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: svc-sa
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
    name: http
  selector:
    app: nginx
  sessionAffinity: ClientIP
  sessionAffinityConfig:
    clientIP:
      timeoutSeconds: 3600
```

So, this service would route the request to the same backend (Pod), depending on the source IP address if the request.

You need to set a service anyways in front of the application B targeting the two pods. Now, the problem here is that your application A is acting as proxy, so all the requests will be considered from application A.

I know this is now a complete answer, but you might be able to do something in the application A, header wise (X-Forwarded-For), to bypass Pod A IP address, by the the IP address of the original request.

Comment: ClientIP affinity would not work in my environment because there is many layer of proxy and security between the client and A. Making the Ip not the Ip of the client but the ip of the proxy

Comment: Yeah, that was my point too, unless you can keep the original client IP. With cookies, you have to get an ingress.